# change type of field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

Hy guys,
I want to ask something.

Well there's a field in base which is like this :

```
_name = "stock.location"

_columns = 
{
  'complete_name': fields.function(_complete_name, type='char',string="Full Location Name", store={'stock.location': (_get_sublocations, ['name', 'location_id', 'active'], 10)}),
}
```

and i wanted to change the complete_name field type to Char in my wizard with my own custome model named : "compute.location.wizard", how do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the old api:

```
_inherit = "stock.location"

_columns = 
{
  # change the all data
  # change anything you want 
  'complete_name': fields.function(_new_method_, type='new_type',string="Full Location Name", store={'stock.location': (_get_sublocations, ['name', 'location_id', 'active'], 10)}),
}
```

but if you can use new api

```
from openerp import models, fields

...

_inherit = "stock.location"

complete_name = fields.Integer(compute="_your_new_method_"); 
# you can change one attribute but in your case i think you need to 
# change  the compute method too
```

Comment: only if you want to change the name of the field because xml don't care about the type. but if this field is used in qweb template in some contcatination i think you don't have to edit the xmls

Comment: They told me just to change the fields.function into fields.char, so the function will not be activated. So, in this case, i shouldn't edit the xml file rigtht? just to change the type of the field from base.

Comment: you want to remove the compute function yest do fields.char and you don't need to change the xml file. only if it give you an error in some qweb template but i don't thing you will have any error because you are not changing the type. you are canceling the compute features

Comment: Thanks mr. i understand now.